# XSLT Translation

Tags: xslt, translation

**I am trying to transform from one xml to another**

**input**

```
<Surcharge>
  <CommercialVehicle desc="Commercial Vehicle">395.00</CommercialVehicle> 
  <EnhancedElectrical desc="Enhanced Electrical">395.00</EnhancedElectrical> 
  <AirConditioningHeating desc="Air Conditioning/Heating">395.00</AirConditioningHeating> 
</Surcharge>
```

**desired output**

```
<Options>
 <Option>
  <OptionId>0</OptionId> 
  <OptionDesc>Commercial Vehicle</OptionDesc> 
  <OptionName>Commercial Vehicle</OptionName> 
  <RetailRate>395.00</RetailRate> 
  <NetRate>395.00</NetRate> 
  <IsSurcharge>false</IsSurcharge> 
  </Option>
 <Option>
  <OptionId>0</OptionId> 
  <OptionDesc>Enhanced Electrical</OptionDesc> 
  <OptionName>Enhanced Electrical</OptionName> 
  <RetailRate>395.00</RetailRate> 
  <NetRate>395.00</NetRate> 
  <IsSurcharge>false</IsSurcharge> 
  </Option>
....
</Options>
```

**I am using following XSL**

```
<Options>
  <xsl:for-each select="//Rate[(CvCvty = $vProg) and (MonthTerm=$vMonthTerm) and (MileageTerm=$vMileageTerm) and (Deductible=$vDeductible)]/Surcharge">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string-length(.//@desc)>0">
        <Option>
          <OptionId>0</OptionId>
          <OptionDesc>
            <xsl:value-of select=".//@desc"/>
          </OptionDesc>
          <OptionName>
            <xsl:value-of select=".//@desc"/>
          </OptionName>
          <RetailRate>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </RetailRate>
          <NetRate>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </NetRate>
          <IsSurcharge>false</IsSurcharge>
        </Option>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
</Options>
```

**But somehow i am getting this output, can someone help me figure out what has to be changed**

```
<Options>
 <Option>
  <OptionId>0</OptionId> 
  <OptionDesc>Commercial Vehicle</OptionDesc> 
  <OptionName>Commercial Vehicle</OptionName> 
  <RetailRate>395.00395.00395.00</RetailRate> 
  <NetRate>395.00395.00395.00</NetRate> 
  <IsSurcharge>false</IsSurcharge> 
  </Option>
</Options>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your foreach is only selecting the single surcharge element, you need to change it to select the child nodes by putting /* at the end.

This will put the context on the element you're interested in, therefore you should use `@desc` instead of the `.//@desc` syntax.

Comment: If you click the tick icon next to this question it'll mark it as the answer, thanks muchly :)